# Files for FTP in cms Drupal

Tags: drupal, ftp

How can I find files for FTP in cms Drupal,where I can edit the code? There are a lot of folders and files, how to understand them? How or where can I see the required file pathes?

Comment: If you're asking these questions you probably shouldn't be making code changes just yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your files in `/sites/all` dir.
Your theme(s) should be in `/sites/all/themes` and modules in `/sites/all/modules`, libraries in `/sites/all/libraries`. Don't change files out of `/sites/all`. By "your" I mean also on themes and modules you download/buy.